# How to convert char to byte?

Tags: java, string, casting, arrays

I was studying an open source code where I came across the following line

```
stringBytes[i] = (byte) (stringChars[i] & 0x00FF);
```

Can someone explain what is actually happening in this line ???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Char consists of 2 bytes in Java and of course byte is single byte.

So in this operation:

```
stringBytes[i] = (byte) stringChars[i] & 0x00FF
```

A char value (16 bits) is being **binary ANDED** with number 0x00FF (binary: 0000 0000 1111 1111) to make it one byte.

By binary ANDING with `8 0s and 8 1s` you're basically masking off 8 left most OR most significant bits (MSB) of the char value thus leaving only 8 right most or least significant bits (LSB) intact. Then code is assigning resulting values to a byte by using cast `(byte)`, which is otherwise an `int` value.

Comment: You are masking off the 8 LEFT most bits, and keeping the RIGHT most bits.  With the and operator, the zeroes in LEFT part of the mask force the result to be zero.

Answer (score 2):

ANDing with 0x00FF retains only the last 8 significant bit and zeros others bits.

```
E.g.:
0xD2A5 & 0x00FF = 1101001010100101 & 0000000011111111 = 0000000010100101 = A5
```

Comment: I'm sure the A5 should really be a 0xA5 - Just for the sake of consistency.